# How to get the product of two RDDs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Am new to spark. I have two RDD's and want to generate resulted RDD on them as below.

```
val rdd1 =  Array(1, 2)
val rdd2 =  Array(a, b, c)

val resultRDD = [(1,a), (1,b), (1,c), (2,a), (2,b), (2,c)]
```

Can anyone help me on what transformations or actions I need to use to generate **resultRDD** like above. FYI, I am writing in scala.

**EDIT**

Thanks. spark cartesian works for me as below.

```
    val data = Array('a', 'b')
    val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(data)

    val data2 = Array(1, 2, 3)
    val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(data2)

    rdd1.cartesian(rdd2).foreach(println)
```

Comment: Did you try double loop over two arrays?

Comment: double loop?? do we have any built in function?

Comment: Why do you call this "recursively"?

Comment: not exactly "recursive", its a cartesian product.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def cartesian[U](other: RDD[U])(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[(T, U)]
```

> Return the Cartesian product of this RDD and another one, that is, the RDD of all pairs of elements (a, b) where a is in this and b is in other.

[Doc here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)

Answer (score 3):

spark cartesian works for me as below.

```
    val data = Array('a', 'b')
    val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(data)

    val data2 = Array(1, 2, 3)
    val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(data2)

    rdd1.cartesian(rdd2).foreach(println)
```

Comment: Great :) Pand005, since the answer is satisfactory, please consider clicking "accept" on Paul's response.